# Google SlidesApp: replace a slide without breaking the link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have written some code in order to create a Google Slide from a Slide Template.

Here are the steps I'm following to create my destination slide document:

- First, I copy the template slide in my destination document, let's call it 'Overview'. If the Overview document does not exist, I create it. Otherwise I update the existing document. Why ? Simply to preserve its ID and be able to link always the same document in other slides documents.
- I remove the existing slide and replace by the template slide. And to my opinion this is where I have a problem ... See below
- Then, my script replaces the placeholders by the images, charts or   text ... And that's all folks!

Here the code I use to initiate the destination document:

```
function initializePresentation(templatePresentation, dstFolder, dstFileName){
  var dstPresentation = "";

  // Check if output file already exist
  if (fileExists(dstFileName, dstFolder)) {

    // Presentation already exists, open it
    dstPresentation = SlidesApp.openById(
      DriveApp.getFilesByName(dstFileName).next().getId());

    // Remove all slides
    var dstSlides = dstPresentation.getSlides();
    for(i=0; i < dstSlides.length; i++) {
      dstSlides[i].remove();
    } 

    // Copy template slide in destination document
    var templateSlide = templatePresentation.getSlides()[0];
    dstPresentation.appendSlide(templateSlide);
  }
  else {
    // Presentation does not exist, create it
    var dstFile = DriveApp.getFileById(templatePresentation.getId()).
      makeCopy(dstFileName, dstFolder);

    // Open the created presentation
    dstPresentation = SlideApp.openById(dstFile.getId());
  }

  return dstPresentation;
}
```

Now let's link the new generated Overview slide in another document ... It works until I update the Overview !

The behaviour seems normal because first I remove the existing slide in my overview then add the one from my template.

How would you do to not break the link ?
I checked the SlidesApp documentation and did not find a way to set / get the Slide IDs and play with it to maintain links (if links are based on IDs for sure!).

Otherwise, is there a way to emulate kind of:

- CTRL+A + DEL to clean my destination slide
- CTRL+A + CTRL+C to copy from my Template then CTRL+V to paste in my destination slide ?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your current issue of your script?

Comment: Yes of course @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. What is the current issue of your script?

Comment: So you're trying to copy a slide from one presentation to another, and then remove the link so if you change it in the original file it doesn't get updated in the second one?

Comment: I copy a slide from my template file to a destination file. This destination file is linked in another presentation. The action to copy the slide (and replace the old one) breaks the link in my other presentation.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can understand about `I copy a slide from my template file to a destination file.`. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about `This destination file is linked in another presentation.`. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. Can you explain about the detail of it?

Comment: When you manually copy a slide from a presentation to another, you have the possibility to just copy/paste or to link. It means that if the original slide is updated, it is also updated in the presentation you copied in.

Comment: Could you please explain how you're linking the whole slide from one presentation to another? I have seen that behavior for charts and tables, but not for whole slides.

Comment: @AMolina when you copy a slide (select a slide on the left pane, then CTRL+C), then paste in another presentation (CTRL+V), a window appears proposing either to "Do not link" or "Link to original presentation". To know more, have a look here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7009814?visit_id=637196706063883782-1323261155&p=embedded_tables&hl=en&rd=1

Comment: I see it now, for some reason when I tried it yesterday I didn't see the linking menu. The link is going to break when you delete the slides in the Overview presentation, you cannot stop this because each slide has an ID, so when you delete one in Overview and copy one from the template, they will have different IDs, regardless of being "the same". What you can do is re-create the link through the code, getting the [Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides#link) from the existing slides from Overview and then linking the newly copied slides

Comment: Also, [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#setLinkSlide(Slide)) is how you can set the link. Apologies if the explanation sounds convoluted.

Comment: Not sure it answers the question above. The slide is linked into another and I can't include code in the presentation where the slide is included in.